# How to get value from list of dictionaries based on specific key value which does not exist in all dictionaries?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries that is like this:

```
{'name': ['Sam'], 'where': ['London']},
{'name': ['Jon'], 'where': ['NY']},
{'name': ['Jon'], 'hobby': ['fifa']},
{'Age': ['20'], 'Country': ['US']},
```

I do have a dictionary like this that could have a lot of same keys but a lot doesn't have that key too. As in above example, we have name key in first 3, but we don't have name key in the 4th. I am trying to get a list of all values that has key 'name'.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What you want is unclear (nor the link to [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas) or [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy)).

If you simply want the values of name when those exist:

```
l = [{'name': ['Sam'], 'where': ['London']},
     {'name': ['Jon'], 'where': ['NY']},
     {'name': ['Jon'], 'hobby': ['fifa']},
     {'Age': ['20'], 'Country': ['US']},]

out = [d['name'] for d in l if 'name' in d]
# [['Sam'], ['Jon'], ['Jon']]

# or as flat list
out = [name for d in l if 'name' in d for name in d['name']]
# ['Sam', 'Jon', 'Jon']

# or just the first name
out = [d['name'][0] for d in l if 'name' in d]
# ['Sam', 'Jon', 'Jon']
```

Comment: Thanks. However, I am getting this error: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable

Comment: Do you have a None in the list? please provide a reproducible list for which this error happens

Comment: there are errors in the list as well: This is some part form list of dictionary: 
-------------------------------------------------------------------
0        {'select': ['all_cons_columns.column_name'], '...
1               {'select': ['free_mb'], 'where': ['name']}
2        {'insert': ['sessionid', 'entryid', 'statement...
3        error:MERGE /*+ OPT_PARAM('_parallel_syspls_ob...
4        error:MERGE /*+ OPT_PARAM('_parallel_syspls_ob...

-----------------------------------------------------------------------

I am trying to get value paired with select key

Comment: I can't help you without a reproducible input.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to extract all names:

```
data = [
    {'name': ['Sam'], 'where': ['London']},
    {'name': ['Jon'], 'where': ['NY']},
    {'name': ['Jon'], 'hobby': ['fifa']},
    {'Age': ['20'], 'Country': ['US']},
]

names = [item['name'][0] for item in data if 'name' in item]
print(names)
```

Result:

```
['Sam', 'Jon', 'Jon']
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume your data is a list of dicts.

```
data = [{'name': ['Sam'], 'where': ['London']},
{'name': ['Jon'], 'where': ['NY']},
{'name': ['Jon'], 'hobby': ['fifa']},
{'Age': ['20'], 'Country': ['US']},]
```

You can get a sub list of all elements with a name key like this:

```
output = [elem for elem in data if elem.get("name")]
```

Comment: Thanks for your input, I get this error: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'

Comment: Do you have a None in your input? Try this please `output = [elem for elem in data if elem and elem.get("name")]`

Comment: there were None, I removed them using: aaa= {k: v for k, v in df_1_joins_where.items() if v is not None}

however now i get this error as I use that code: argument of type 'int' is not iterable

Comment: seems like your data is not in the same format as your example data

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this. One would be:

```
_list = [{'name': ['Sam'], 'where': ['London']},
{'name': ['Jon'], 'where': ['NY']},
{'name': ['Jon'], 'hobby': ['fifa']},
{'Age': ['20'], 'Country': ['US']}]

print(*(name for d in _list if (name := d.get('name'))))
```

**Output:**

```
['Sam'] ['Jon'] ['Jon']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try a list expression:

```
all_dicts = [{'name': ['Sam'], 'where': ['London']},
{'name': ['Jon'], 'where': ['NY']},
{'name': ['Jon'], 'hobby': ['fifa']},
{'Age': ['20'], 'Country': ['US']}]

dicts_with_name = [d.values() for d in all_dicts if 'name' in d.keys() ]
```

This extracts all values (for all keys) of those dictionaries in the list that have a name field. If you want the key, value pairs, you can `d.items()` instead of `d.values()`